# Base 64 decoding a string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm completely new to ruby-on-rails, I just want to write a small rb programming code that will take input as a string(encoded password), then it will decode the string and return it to the caller. I was trying the below code but not sure what I'm doing, here my purpose of having this code is to use it as a plugin in fluentd.

```
def create_base_64 
  
base64_string = "67382hfuisab3y289321787123890......"

decoded_data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(base64_string))

end
```

In case you are posting the code, could you please provide me with some online programming tool where I can test it online.

Comment: You don't need `StringIO`. `Base64.decode64` returns a string directly to you. Example: `Base64.decode64('SGVsbG8gV29ybGQK')` => `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @Casper thanks for correcting, however, I'm looking forward to a complete code, like how to accept parameters and return the response, could you please help me to show in some online programming tool?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'base64'

def decode_string(encoded_string)
  begin
    Base64.decode64(encoded_string)
  rescue
    puts 'Not a base64 string'
    exit
  end
end

if ARGV.length != 1
  puts 'Missing argument'
  exit
end

puts decode_string(ARGV[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one small request instead of encoding and decoding, if I want to encrypt or decrypt how to achieve that?